# How do I resize an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to resize cross domain iframe to fit content . So in parent.html I write this:

```
$(function () {
    $('iframe').load(function () {
        var h = null;
        if (!h) {
            if (location.hash.match(/^#h(\d+)/)) {
                h = RegExp.$1;
                $(this).css({
                    'height': h + 'px'
                })
                location.hash = ''
            }

        }
    })
})
```

and in child.html i write this:

```
$(function () {
    h = 0
    h = $(document).height()
    console.log(h)
    if (top != self) {
        top.location.replace("http://parentdomain.com/#h" + h);
    }
})
```

it works fine when it loads once, but if I click link in iframe and content changes variable `h` still has first value.  If I open `child.html` in new window `var h` will be changing, but not in iframe.

Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resize action actually doesn't get called again.

If you click a link in the iFrame you should call a function on the parent, or watch the haschange event which is only supported on the more recent browsers.

Comment: I don't know much about jQuery, but we've done that several time with an onload event bound to the iframe :) so it is fitting it's contents every time the content changes (with the exception of ajax calls ;)